# C# Null Coalescing for choosing between an object's properties?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have some classes that look like this:

```
class User{
  long Id;
  string FirstName;
  string Nickname;
}
```

and

```
class Location{
  List<User> Users;
}
```

I need to get a user from the list based on some criteria, then grab their nickname, if any, or their first name otherwise. Usually I would do something like this:

```
User selectedUser = locationObj.Users.First(u => u.Id == 1);
string nameToBeCalledBy = selectedUser.Nickname ?? selectedUser.FirstName;
```

but in my current situation I'm dealing with expression trees that can't handle statement bodies. The best solution I know of is this:

```
locationObj.Users.First(u => u.Id == 1).Nickname ??
locationObj.Users.First(u => u.Id == 1).FirstName
```

which is inefficient and inelegant. Is there a way to null-coalesce an object's property with another property, like so?

```
locationObj.Users.First(u => u.Id == 1).(Nickname ?? FirstName)
```

Comment: You could make a property in User that's just `string PreferredName => Nickname ?? FirstName`.

Answer (score 4):

I would add it to the class

```
class User{
  long Id;
  string FirstName;
  string Nickname;

  string NameToBeCalledBy { 
    get { return this.Nickname ?? this.FirstName; }
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
string nameToBeCalledBy = locationObj.Users.First(u => u.Id == 1).NameToBeCalledBy;
```

Thats kindof what classes were for, in the old days, to keep methods related to an object's data near that data. Although the .Select() answers people have given are also pretty tidy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
string nameToBeCalledBy = locationObj.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == 1)
    .Select(u => u.Nickname ?? u.FirstName)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

First filter the collection to a collection of a single object, then do a selection on that "collection", and then select the only string in that collection.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you'll consider this better approach, but you can do `Where` into `Select`:

```cs
string nameToBeCalledBy = locationObj.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == 1)
    .Select(u => u.Nickname ?? u.FirstName)
    .First(); // consider using FirstOrDefault or Single(OrDefault) based on situation
```

Or just add property or ([extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)) method which will encapsulate the logic:

```cs
class User{
  // ....
  public string NameToBeCalledBy => Nickname ?? FirstName;
}
```

or

```cs
public static class UserExstentions
{
  public static string GetNameToBeCalledBy(this User user) => user.Nickname ?? user.FirstName;
}

// usage
string nameToBeCalledBy = locationObj.Users.First(u => u.Id == 1).GetNameToBeCalledBy();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method:

```
public static TOut Transform<TIn, TOut>(
   this TIn me,
   Func<TIn, TOut> func
) =>
   func(me);
```

```
string nameToBeCalledBy = 
   locationObj
   .Users
   .First(u => u.Id == 1)
   .Transform(u => u.Nickname ?? u.FirstName)
```